# You are running version v6.10.3 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI v6

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I am having trouble with this error, my project need run angular/cli version 1.7.4 and `Nodejs 6.10.3` .But the past I used angular cli version 6 and now I want to downgrade to angular cli 1.7.4 but I don't know how to downgrade angular cli version 6 at my global. I try to use `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` and then I install the version I want by command `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.4` but when I check ng -v it's still have a error in picture

[image]

**P/S:** I were updated my npm to latest version to make sure can remove angular cli version but still don't work

Comment: Try clean cache with `npm cache verify` or `npm cache clean` (for npm version < 5) after uninstall. Also make sure you have a correct version installed locally in the project folder. Because ng-cli first try local package and then the global one.

Answer (score -1):

Keep your global package running at the highest version. If a project needs CLI 1.x, use the `npm run` commands instead.

Any npm commands run use the project's CLI, not your global version.